# Java code will not locate the desired String in my Txt file

Tags: java, search, text

I have just gotten into java, and i was working on an elementary project.
I tried to create a program which would locate the desired string within a txt which stored some activities, and the id associated with them (e.g:
1 Sleep
2 Exercise
3 Socializing
4 Studying
5 Transportation
6 Eating)

The code is as follows

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ReadNSearchFile {
    private static Scanner x;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Java crap\\Activities.txt";
        String searchTerm = "Sleep";
        
        readRecord(searchTerm, filepath);
    }
    public static void readRecord(String searchTerm, String filepath) { //it will search for the ID
        boolean found = false;
        String ID = ""; String activity = "";
        
        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            x.useDelimiter("[\n\s]"); //used to separate fields in a file eg words
            
            while(x.hasNext() && !found) {
                ID = x.next();
                activity = x.next();
                if(activity.equals(searchTerm)) {
                    found = true; 
                }
            }
            
            if(found) {
                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID:" + ID + "Activity: " + activity);
        }else if(!found) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Record not found");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "error");
        }
    
}
}
```

The desired activity is contained within the text, however is not located through the code.
Why is this?

Comment: That code doesn't do anything at all, since it fails to compile: `error: illegal escape character` pointing to `\s`

Comment: really? for me it runs, it just says that the string was not located

Comment: Have you tried **researching** the problem, e.g. a simply debugging exercise of printing the value of `activity` to see what the code is actually getting? I bet that the **first value is `Sleep\r`**, since you are on Windows and line separators are `\r\n`, and you split on `\n` but not `\r`.

Comment: @f1sh Actually, my Eclipse compiles it fine, but `javac` fails, though javac 14 gives a different error: `error: text blocks are a preview feature and are disabled by default.`

Comment: Actually, it seemed to work if i changed it to \\s as long as i searched for "Sleep" "Socializing" or "Transportation". In other cases it seemed to register the ID instead of the activity

Comment: @Prat If you use `\\s`, then there is no need for `\n` since `\\s` means `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` which includes `\n` as you can see.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the feedback. As previously mentioned, doing so seems to work as long as i searched for "Sleep" "Socializing" or "Transportation". In other cases it seemed to register the ID instead of the activity

Comment: I decided to output the activity with each iteration of the while loop, and it printed Sleep 2 Socializing 4 and Transportation 6 (on separate lines). Dk why it happens tho

Comment: @Prat You need to remove the `useDelimiter()` call, and leave the delimiter as the default of `"\\s+"`. When you change it to `"[\n\\s]"` or `"[\\s]"` or `"\\s"` or any such pattern that doesn't have `+` at the end, then the `\r\n` line separator of Windows becomes **two** delimiters, with an empty string between them, which means you get token pairs `["1", "Sleep"], ["", "2"], ["Exercise", ""], ["3", "Socializing"], ["", "4"], ["Studying", ""], ["5", "Transportation"], ["", "6"], ["Eating", ""]`

Comment: @Andreas That did the trick. Thank you so much for the assistance, appreciated.